# Verification of hadith

Tags: hadith, source-identification

When you stand and pray and say” Allahu Akbar” Allah stands before you and the minute your mind goes wandering on silly things in life. Allah turns his face away from you and says (is there something better than me taking you away from me)

*Is the above hadith Authentic and if so from which book?*

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it’s Authentic:

> رُوِیَ عَنِ الصَّادِقِ عَلَیهِ السَّلَامُ قَالَ: إِذَا قَامَ الْعَبْدُ
>   إِلَى الصَّلَاةِ أَقْبَلَ اللَّهُ عَزَّ وَ جَلَّ عَلَیْهِ بِوَجْهِهِ
>   فَلَا یَزَالُ مُقْبِلًا عَلَیْهِ حَتَّى یَلْتَفِتَ ثَلَاثَ مَرَّاتٍ
>   فَإِذَا الْتَفَتَ ثَلَاثَ مَرَّاتٍ أَعْرَضَ عَنْهُ

Imam [Ja'far al-Sadiq(a.s.)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ja%27far_al-Sadiq):when you stand to pray, Allah pay attention to you. And when you take no notice or forget Allah or think about silly things for the third time, Allah turns his face away from you.

And the source is" [Wasā'il al-Shīʿa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Was%C4%81%27il_al-Sh%C4%AB%CA%BFa) “and " [Bihar al-Anwar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bihar_al-Anwar)".

Answer (score 1):

It is Authentic, it has been narrated in a number of books.  It has been narrated in [Sunnan Annasa'i](http://sunnah.com/nasai/13/17), and is Hasan.  Other books in which it has been narrated are:  [Abi Dawood](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/2/520) in which it is Da'eef, and in [Jami'i Tirmidhi](http://sunnah.com/urn/730960), in which the hadith is saheeh:

> إِنَّ اللَّهَ أَمَرَكُمْ بِالصَّلاَةِ فَإِذَا صَلَّيْتُمْ فَلاَ
>   تَلْتَفِتُوا فَإِنَّ اللَّهَ يَنْصِبُ وَجْهَهُ لِوَجْهِ عَبْدِهِ فِي
>   صَلاَتِهِ مَا لَمْ يَلْتَفِتْ
>
> Allah commands you to perform Salat, and when you perform Salat then
>   do not turn away, for Allah is facing the face of His worshipers as
>   long as he does not turn away.

And there are similar Ahadeeth in regards to spitting in front of your during salat and others, which I will not mention in my answer to this question.